# Setting StrongAuthenticationUserDetails PhoneNumber for AzureAD via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

That title really flows.

When setting up computers for use with Azure Active Directory, we would have IT do initial setup and config. This included the first sign in and joining to Azure Active Directory. When signing in it forces you to select a verification method. We would use our desk phone or cell phone for ease.

The time has come for us to update that second factor phone number. I know of a way to manually do it via the Azure AD Web UI, but I am looking for a scripted way to set that number in PowerShell.

Here is how I retrieve the number via PowerShell.

```
Get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "email@emailaddress.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationUserDetails
```

That code returns this info:

```
ExtensionData                     : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AlternativePhoneNumber            :
Email                             :
OldPin                            :
PhoneNumber                       : +1 5554445555
Pin                               :
```

However, there seems to be no similar option for setting the StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.

All my searches just turned up how to bulk enable 2-factor authentication, which is not what I want to do. I want to leave the StrongAuthentication the same while only updating the phone number.

Comment: I encountered the same problem one week ago. The MSOL cmdlets seem to lack a way to do this. Same goes for the AzureAD cmdlets.

Comment: @bluuf Sorry the post.  Should not read that fast.  Anyways, It appears there is read-only access for powershell.  There is even opened ticket for that - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13539441-phone-factor .  There is a plan to do it, but no ETA.  Is an answer that it is not possible for you an answer?

Comment: I hoped there was any way to do it programatically :/ I'm not sure if I should wait a few more days to see if there is any kind of workaround at all.

Comment: @BožoStojković you should wait for a few days.  Maybe someone has some kind of workaround.

Comment: @BožoStojković It occured to me that you maybe able to create a watir automated proces via powershell.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment, it appears there is read-only access for powershell.

There is even opened ticket for that on [Azure feedback](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WATIRForNETWatiNApproaches08ReleaseAndAutomatingIEFromPowerShell.aspx).

There is a plan to do it, but no ETA. My guess is that you will have to wait if you want to use powershell only.

As workaround, you could use **powershell** & **[watir for .NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WATIRForNETWatiNApproaches08ReleaseAndAutomatingIEFromPowerShell.aspx)** OR [Watin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/) with [Watin recorder](http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/) to automatize it via Internet Explorer.  As I don't have a testing Azure; I can not create workable code for you.

Using *Watin* and powershell - you could check: https://cmille19.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/internet-explorer-automation-with-watin/

*The following text and code, I wanted to backup it here, was taken from the above page (all credits to the author):*

> Next click the record button and click the HTML element you want to
>   automate. Then stop the WatIN recorder and click copy code to
>   clipboard icon. This will produce some C# code that just needs to be
>   translated into PowerShell:

```
// Windows
WatiN.Core.IE window = new WatiN.Core.IE();

// Frames
Frame frame_sd_scoreboard = window.Frame(Find.ByName("sd") && Find.ByName("scoreboard"));

// Model
Element __imgBtn0_button = frame_sd_scoreboard.Element(Find.ByName("imgBtn0_button"));

// Code
__imgBtn0_button.Click();
window.Dispose();
```

> So, I now know the name of the button and that it is 3 frames deep. A
>   little WatIN object exploration later, I came up with the follow
>   script, which clicks a button every 50 mintues.

```
#Requires -version 2.0
#powershell.exe -STA

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( "$ProfileDirLibrariesWatiN.Core.dll" ) | out-null
$ie = new-object WatiN.Core.IE("https://sd.acme.com/CAisd/pdmweb.exe")
$scoreboard  = $ie.frames | foreach {$_.frames } | where {$_.name –eq ‘sd’} |  foreach {$_.frames } | where {$_.name –eq ‘scoreboard’}
$button = $scoreboard.Element("imgBtn0_button")

while ($true)
{
    $button.Click()
    #Sleep for 50 minutes
    [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(3000000)
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. Your commands set the phonenumber of the user and NOT the phonenumber of the MFA settings.

Comment: Well, since there doesn't appear to be another solution, I will accept this and give it bounty, unless someone else gives a better answer. For now, I guess some javascript in console will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: the code is provided as-is. It might happen that it'll stop working in case MS changes Azure Portal interface.

---

I'm using the following Greasemonkey script to update alternate email and phone (phone [can be updated via Graph API now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) so the script will be useful for email only):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 548177
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @namespace https://portal.azure.com
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // press alt+shift+g
  if (e.keyCode == 71 && e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
    const url = document.URL;
    const regex = /https:\/\/portal.azure.com\/#blade\/Microsoft_AAD_IAM\/UserDetailsMenuBlade\/UserAuthMethods\/userId\/[\w-]+\/adminUnitObjectId[\/]*\?\w+=(\d{9})&\w+=([\w\.-@]+)/;
    const params = url.match(regex);
    const allAuthRows = document.getElementsByClassName('ext-userauthenticationmethods-section-row');
    const authRowsArray = Array.from(allAuthRows);
    let emailRow;
    let phoneRow;
    let i;
    for (i =0; i < authRowsArray.length; i++) {
      if (authRowsArray[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].data === 'Email') {
        emailRow = authRowsArray[i]
      }
      if (authRowsArray[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes.length > 1) {
        if (authRowsArray[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].data === 'Phone') {
          phoneRow = authRowsArray[i]
        }
      }
    }

    const emailInput = emailRow.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[2];
    const phoneInput = phoneRow.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[2];
    const event = new Event('input', {
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    if (params[1] !== '000000000') {
      phoneInput.value = `+48 ${params[1]}`;
      phoneInput.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    if (params[2] !== 'null') {
      emailInput.value = params[2];
      emailInput.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      const buttonArr = document.getElementsByClassName('azc-toolbarButton-container fxs-portal-hover');
      const saveButton = Array.from(buttonArr).find(e => e.title === 'Save');
      saveButton.click();
    } , 2000);    

  }
}, false);
})();
```

It requires you to open Azure portal with querystring like this (I do it with PowerShell):

```
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UserDetailsMenuBlade/UserAuthMethods/userId/$($u.ObjectId)/adminUnitObjectId/?param1=$newPhone&param2=$newMail
```

How to use it:

- open only one tab at a time, otherwise you'll receive `Unable to sign-in` error
- from time to time you'll receive that error anyway, so just wait
- to trigger the script press `Alt+Shift+g` after the site is loaded (you can change the shortcut in first `if`)
- once the data is updated and saved, press `Ctrl+w` to close the current tab and press `Alt+Tab` to switch to previous window (should be PowerShell)
- you're still free to use the code to update the phone. Make sure to change country code (currently `+48` for Poland)